# Can we make structured page data for any type of entities?

Tags: google-apps-script, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have an encyclopedia website for plants care (flowers, trees, vegetables etc.). Each plant has a table of environment requirements like:

- how much light need per day
- what kind of soil needed
- how much water and moisture needed
- temperature range that can grow

Can I make an structured page to show this table on Google Search?

Something like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Plant",
"plantCare": {"@type": "PlantCare","sun": "medium","soil": "alkaline soil             - a mixture of leaf and forest soil","moisture": "slightly     humid","temperature": "25 ° C"},"image": "http://nargil.ir/plant/images/plants/Euphorbia Pulcherrima.jpg","scientificName": "EUPHORBIA     PULCHERRIMA","family": "EUPHORBIACEAE","genus": "EUPHORBIA ","native":     "Mexsico"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web? What you already tried something?

Comment: What is the relation with Google App Script here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no vocabulary for this type of thing (flowers, trees, vegetables, etc).

Of course, you cannot invent object types and properties.

```
https://schema.org/Plant
```

(Return 404 Not Found).

### Schema Full Hierarchy

Select the most specific schema related to your data (Again for now **no** schema for plants - nice idea for schema - by the way).
https://schema.org/docs/full.html

Also, for now, google not supporting this rich snippet.

### productontology

http://www.productontology.org/

> This service provides ca. 300,000 precise definitions for types of
>   product or services that extend the schema.org and GoodRelations
>   standards for e-commerce markup, e.g.

Apple example:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "https://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "product",
  "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Apple", 
  "name": "Apple",
  "category": "Fruits",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/apple.jpg",
  "description": "An apple is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an apple tree (Malus Domestica)."
}
</script>
```

#### schema.org Github issue related:

**"What is Fruits vocabulary in schema.org and how to implement it?"**

> Note that you can always use the types from www.productontology.org
>   for more precise markup for any plant or species.
>   www.productontology.org will provide a valid class definition for
>   anything that has a Wikipedia entry, and this is likely any
>   scientifically accepted plant or species on earth.
>
> [(issue 2253)](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/2253)