# Schema.org type for collectibles or catalogs?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

There is the coins catalog https://colnect.com/en/coins/list/year/1889

Each item in list has [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) Microdata, some items in marketplace have the `offers` property. For example: [this stamp](https://colnect.com/en/stamps/stamp/2376-Snowstorm_-_Steamer_off_a_Harbours_Mouth-Birth_Bicentenary_of_JMW_Turner_painter-United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_Northern_Ireland).

Recently the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) began to show error instead of warning for missing `offers` property on `Product` pages against it still described as recommended property in [product rich result docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product). Also here are 'Either "offers", "review", or "aggregateRating" should be specified' errors in Google Search Console.

What kind of structured data will be most suitable for those items?

How to avoid these structured data errors? Will it be correct to have [`Thing`](https://schema.org/Thing) type for catalog items and then change it to [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) when the item will be placed in marketplace?

**Update 2019-10-15:** Structured Data for [mentioned above stamp](https://colnect.com/en/stamps/stamp/2376-Snowstorm_-_Steamer_off_a_Harbours_Mouth-Birth_Bicentenary_of_JMW_Turner_painter-United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_Northern_Ireland) are [here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fcolnect.com%2Fen%2Fstamps%2Fstamp%2F2376-Snowstorm_-_Steamer_off_a_Harbours_Mouth-Birth_Bicentenary_of_JMW_Turner_painter-United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_Northern_Ireland). At the moment it has `offers` so there are 3 warnings only.

And [Structured Data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fcolnect.com%2Fen%2Fstamps%2Fstamp%2F16993-Wilhelm_Miklas_1872-1956_federal_president-Fighting_lungdiseases-Austria) for [some other stamp](https://colnect.com/en/stamps/stamp/16993-Wilhelm_Miklas_1872-1956_federal_president-Fighting_lungdiseases-Austria) without `offers`, here is the missing `offers` filed error.

It seems Google does not allow schema.org [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) markup without `offers`.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer your issue (Next time please add some code examples).

**In general in this URL:**

https://colnect.com/en/stamps/stamp/2376-Snowstorm_-_Steamer_off_a_Harbours_Mouth-Birth_Bicentenary_of_JMW_Turner_painter-United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_Northern_Ireland

Without this warning:

`'Either "offers", "review", or "aggregateRating" should be specified'`
- But read this:
https://www.checkerboard.com/web-development/fix-offers-review-aggregaterating-specified/

**Product VS Thing** - it's better to use more specific object-type (This is not related to the "marketplace" option to pay Online) (Google rich-snippet related to products).

productontology:
For coins/Sports Cards and so on you could add extra-data by productontology (not mandatory):
http://www.productontology.org/

**Related:**
[Can we make structured page data for any type of entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564853/can-we-make-structured-page-data-for-any-type-of-entities/57570151#57570151)

Comment: thank you for reply, some code samples were added.
It seems productontology is used to extend [Product](https://schema.org/Product) data but Google doesn't see "product" here.
GoodRelations uses not very convenient RDF format.

Will there be any benefits from using own [HTML5 microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html) vocabularies?